# Is it possible to make 'cart' with django Class Based View?

Tags: django, web, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make a simple e-commerce website and followed some tutorials.

However, the author of the book used complicated function based view to make cart function..

there are bunch of session stuffs.. and I don't understand the logic..

and I am trying to think the other way..

what about using database to store all the cart related data, and

use CBV to build it?

for example,

CartListView to see the contents of the cart, and CartUpdateView to change the quantity..

then are they going to be two different pages? separated page that user should go to the

different page to change the value??

please help me T T

Answer (score 0):

You can access the session in any sort of CBV as `self.request.session` and a "shopping cart" is normally stored therein.

You'll certainly need to implement a `CartListView` to see what's in it, or possibly a `CartEditView` to show the cart with options to edit the quantities and delete anything that shouldn't be in there.

Adding products to the cart may well be an "Add" button on a ProductDetailView or lots of add buttons in a ProductListView. You might add a POST handler method to these views which are otherwise read-only (GET-only) bt default. Or you might make them FormViews, even though the form would be hidden and filled/POSTed by JS rather than the shopper doing anything other than clicking "add".

And then there will be a CheckoutView.

Check https://djangopackages.org/ (put "cart" in the search box). this will throw up several shopping cart things which might be the code you want, or the source of which might be a valuable learning resource before you end up rolling your own.

Comment: it is not really possible because I have tried it but it doesn't work properly. I am also excited if it is possible to make it with generic views only.

Comment: @vijay are you sure it's not a failure to explicitly save the session when necessary ( `request.session.modified=True`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved). Assume Django does work as per documentation. I've never yet found a bug though have stumbled over a few documented "features".

Comment: @nigel222 thank you so much for your explanation with details! as a newbie, it is not easy to learn, but maybe I can try:) thanks my friend!